# Shell_exec not executing php files

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm trying to run a shell_exec query by pressing a button.
But it does not seem to execute anything. I checked php.ini and it isn't disabled. I'm trying to execute a php file in a different directory 
/var/www/html/root/download_handler.php. It doesn't seem to work.

 

Here's my code. I hope anyone knows what i can do to fix this?

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

if (isset($_POST['download'])) {

    $site = $_POST['site'];
    $wait = $_POST['wait'];
    $folder = $_POST['folder'];
    $strpos = strpos($site, "http://");

    if (empty($site) || empty($wait) || empty($folder)) {

        $error = Error::display("Input fields left empty", "alert");

    } else {

        if ($strpos === false) {

            $error = Error::display("Incorrect URL Format. Example: http://example.com/", "alert");

        } else {

            $username = $_SESSION['username'];


            $error = Error::display($site . $wait . $folder . $username, "success");
            shell_exec("screen php /var/www/html/download_handler.php download $site $folder $wait $username");


        }

    }

}

}

?>
```

Comment: You could try using curl to yourself with the arguments to that php. Or you could open an output buffer and set the $_GET values before including the php to execute directly. Personally I just like to avoid using `shell_exec` at all possible.

Comment: How could this be achieved in CURL? I'm not too familiar with using it.

Comment: Well, curl is like opening a web browser to a URL... basically. It returns the output of the url you go to (if you want it). Since your `download_handler.php` looks to be at the root of a website, you should be able to hit it using curl to `https://yourdomain.com/download_handler.php?param&param&etc`. You'll need to read up on curl in php though. Its just an idea, and I'm not pressuring you towards it, especially if you've never used it.

Comment: Alright, I set it up with CURL. But it seems like my target script can't shell_exec the screen command, It can run the php script alone.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not at all familiar with trying to use `screen` with `php` in command line, so I'm of no help there ;)